# How do i add year (date) criteria to DSUM?

Tags: excel, date, format, wildcard

I have a database that looks like this:

```
(A1)Client              (B1) Date                       (C1) debts
(A2)1                   (B2) Mon 2 november 2008        (C2) 1500$
(A3)2                   (B3) Thu 7 february 2008        (C3) 1000$
(A4)3                   (B4) Sat 28 March 2009          (C4) 800$
(A5)4                   (B5) Mon 16 March 2009          (C5) 1200$
```

The date format is 24/11/2008.
I have to use DSUM to get the sum of the debts clients had in 2008.

I already did a table that looks like this:

```
(A7)Client             (A7) Date                        (C7) debts
                       (A9) 2008
```

and the function `=DSUM(A1:C5,3,A7:C8)` but it seems I can't extract the value of 2008 from the date 24/11/2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to store dates as text, change your 2008 to 1/1/2008 and format as "YYYY"
To use DSUM to sum entries that fall in a calendar year you will have to define the start and end date, so your filter data will look like this:

```
Client  Date           Date
debts   =">=1/1/2008"  ="<1/1/2009"
```